# Replace image with image name in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, large-data, vba

I have a spreadsheet with images in one of the columns. When I click on the image, I can see the image name in the top left corner.

[image: Screenshot of Excel]

Instead of the images, I would like its name to appear in the column. I can't do this manually because there are over 10000 rows. Is there a way to get the image name in a column?

Comment: Hi. This assumes that all pictures are properly named in Excel. Is this the case?

Comment: @Hadi, each image has a distinct name. I don't know what it means to be 'properly named'.

Comment: The images are a set of shapes which has an array of names... That can be set according to their content and can be read by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this then, and I hope it will work for you.

```
Sub ImageNamesInCells()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim actSheet As Worksheet
    Dim aShape As Shape

    Set actSheet = ActiveSheet 'or better ThisWorkBook.sheets("SheetName")


    For Each aShape In actSheet.Shapes
        oneShape.TopLeftCell = oneShape.Name 'assuming that TopLeftCell refers to the cell where the image is.
    Next


End Sub
```

Good luck!